# UILabel reverts to default text on iPhone rotation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilabel

This is a slightly odd one which I'm not sure where to start debugging. I have a UILabel on a standard view which I update the text based on certain conditions. From the IB I have set default text that reads 'Loading...' and then the viewDidAppear method updates the text based on the conditions. This works fine, however, if I then rotate my iPhone (or simulator) it reverts the UILabel back to the standard text of 'Loading...'.

What's interesting is that when I view it on an iPad, both simulator and actual device it doesn't change the text back to the default and acts as I would expect.

I have tried detecting an orientation change and resetting the text but that has no effect, it's a bit like the label has become locked to default state.

Happy to provide code if necessary but I'm really not sure what code is relevant as it's a straight forward label and updating it's text.

Thanks

[image: Portrait View]

[image: Landscape View]

```
import UIKit

class PredictionViewController: UIViewController {

    var predictionData: Predictions!
    var embeddedVC: PredictionsTableViewController?

    @IBOutlet weak var messageTextBox: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var predictionSubmitButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var predictionSubmitButtonHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        //self.messageTextBox.isEditable = false
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(settingChanged(notification:)), name: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
        if (preferences.object(forKey: "regID") == nil)
        {
            loadLoginScreen()
        }
        else {
            let sv = UIViewController.displaySpinner(onView: self.view)
            let predictionStatus = preferences.object(forKey: "predictionStatus") as! String

            switch (predictionStatus) {
                case "inplay":
                    setInplay(view: self)
                case "finished":
                    setFinished(view: self)
                case "predict":
                    setPredict(view: self)
                default:
                    self.messageTextBox.text = "Error!"
            }
            if (self.messageTextBox.isHidden) {
                self.messageTextBox.isHidden = false
            }
            UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: sv)
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "predictionSegue") {
            if let vc = segue.destination as? PredictionsTableViewController {
                // get a reference to the embedded VC
                self.embeddedVC = vc
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func settingChanged(notification: NSNotification) {
        let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
        let predictionStatus = preferences.object(forKey: "predictionStatus") as! String

        switch (predictionStatus) {
            case "inplay":
                setInplay(view: self)
            case "finished":
                setFinished(view: self)
            case "predict":
                setPredict(view: self)
            default:
                messageTextBox.text = "Error!"
        }
    }

    func setInplay(view: PredictionViewController) {
        view.messageTextBox.text = "In Play!"
        view.predictionSubmitButtonHeight.constant = 0
    }

    func setFinished(view: PredictionViewController) {
        view.messageTextBox.text = "Finished!"
        view.predictionSubmitButtonHeight.constant = 0
    }

    func setPredict(view: PredictionViewController) {
        view.messageTextBox.text = "Predict Now!"
        view.predictionSubmitButton.isEnabled = true
        view.predictionSubmitButton.setTitle("Submit", for: .normal)
        view.predictionSubmitButtonHeight.constant = 58
    }

    @IBAction func predictionSubmitButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
        let sv = UIViewController.displaySpinner(onView: self.view)
        CheckTime(finished: { isSuccess in

            switch (isSuccess) {
            case "inplay":
                preferences.set("inplay", forKey: "predictionStatus")
                //too late alert
            case "finished":
                preferences.set("finished", forKey: "predictionStatus")
                //too late alert
            case "predict":
                preferences.set("predict", forKey: "predictionStatus")

                if let predictionData = self.embeddedVC?.getPredictionData() {
                    //send back to website
                    let regID = preferences.object(forKey: "regID")
                    let url = URL(string: "[URL]")
                    let session = URLSession.shared

                    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
                    request.httpMethod = "POST"
                    let bodyData = "{}"

                    request.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
                    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
                        (data, response, error) in

                        guard let data = data, let _ = response, error == nil else
                        {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async(
                                execute: {
                                    UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: sv)
                                    self.displayAlertMessage(message: "response error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))", type: "error")
                            }
                            )
                            return
                        }

                        do {

                            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                            let predictionResult = try decoder.decode(ReturnData.self, from: data)

                            DispatchQueue.main.async(
                                execute: {
                                    if (predictionResult.success) {
                                        self.displayAlertMessage(message: predictionResult.message, type: "message", title: "Predictions Received")
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        self.displayAlertMessage(message: "response error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))", type: "error")
                                    }
                                    UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: sv)
                                }
                            )
                        } catch {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async(
                                execute: {
                                    UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: sv)
                                    self.displayAlertMessage(message: "response error: \(error)", type: "error")
                            }
                            )
                            return
                        }
                    })

                    task.resume()
                }
            default:
                UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: sv)
                self.messageTextBox.text = "Error!"
                preferences.set("error", forKey: "predictionStatus")
            }
            preferences.synchronize()

            if (self.messageTextBox.isHidden) {
                self.messageTextBox.isHidden = false
            }

        })
    }

}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            print("Landscape")
            //imageView.image = UIImage(named: const2)
        } else {
            print("Portrait")
            //imageView.image = UIImage(named: const)
        }
        self.messageTextBox.text = "Error!"
}
```

Comment: Have you written any code in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: Can you share the whole code for this screen?

Comment: No, I haven't added either of those methods. I tried to add a viewWillTransition method to reupdate the text but that got called but didn't change the text.

Comment: Added the ViewController to the question

Comment: Did you call `super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)` when you tested with `viewWillTransition`?

Comment: Have you used font based on `size classes`?

Comment: Yes super.viewWillTransition is used. - Added to question

Comment: I am using font based size classes so I have one for wRhR but the only difference that I can see is one is font size 17 and the other size 30. No other attributes are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can You use this Delegate method for screen orientation.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in

    }, completion: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in
        //refresh view once rotation is completed not in will transition as it returns incorrect frame size.Refresh here
        **//---> Set the text for label here.**

    })
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
}
```

Comment: This has done the trick, thanks! Any idea why it was only a problem on iPhone (8) and not iPad (12.9 inch)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you should take your code off `viewDidAppear` and put inside `viewDidLoad`.

If you don't want to use the code in other orientation, you should uncheck for all other orientations and only choose the one you want to be implemented, that will fix your problem, however if you want to works in other orientations, try to do what I said and see if it works.

Even none of what I just said works, try to look around your code if you have a condition to changes the text when transition happens.

One more thing, just a tip, avoid putting too much code inside of a simple action, try to refactoring in other Methods and then call it inside your action.

Comment: It was originally in viewDidLoad but it doesn't run all the methods required in there. Thanks for the tip, this is my first app so it does need a bit better structure!